# characteristic function for the beta distribution

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the characteristic function of the beta distribution with R for a lot of different alphas and betas; unfortunately I am running into numerical problems.

First i was using the package `CharFun` and the function `cfX_Beta(t, alpha, beta)` which seems to be working fine for most cases, but for example for `alpha=121.3618` and `beta=5041.483` it fails completely (see example below, `Re(cfX_Beta(t, alpha, beta))` and `Im(cfX_Beta(t, alpha, beta))` should always be in the interval [-1,1] which is not the case).

Then I decided to obtain the characteristic function by integration. This method delivers believable results for `alpha=121.3618` and `beta=5041.483` but for other combinations the integration fails. (Error: "the integral is probably divergent"). Increasing `rel.tol` for the integral did not help either. On the contrary, for other values of alpha and beta I would get the error: "roundoff error was detected".

So my question is:
Is there another way to get reliable results for the characteristic function of beta distribution for all possible combinations of alpha and beta?

Am I making any obvious mistakes?

```
library(CharFun)
abc<-function(x,t,a,b) {
   return( dbeta(x,a,b)*cos(t*x))
}
dfg<-function(x,t,a,b) {
   return( dbeta(x,a,b)*sin(t*x))
}
hij<-function(t,a,b) {
  intRe=rep(0,length(t))
  intIm=rep(0,length(t))
  i<-complex(1,0,1)
  for (j in 1:length(t)) {
    intRe[j]<-integrate(abc,lower=0,upper=1,t[j],a,b)$value
    intIm[j]<-integrate(dfg,lower=0,upper=1,t[j],a,b)$value
  }
  return(intRe+intIm*i)
}

alpha<-1
beta<-1

t <- seq(-100, 100, length.out = 501)
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
alpha<-1
beta<-1
plotGraf(function(t)
   hij(t, alpha, beta), t, title = "CF alpha=1
beta=1")
plotGraf(function(t)
   cfX_Beta(t, alpha, beta), t, title = "CF Charfun alpha=1
beta=1")

alpha<-121.3618
beta<-5041.483
plotGraf(function(t)
  hij(t, alpha, beta), t, title = "CF alpha=121.3618 beta=5041.483")
plotGraf(function(t)
  cfX_Beta(t, alpha, beta), t, title = "CF Charfun alpha=121.3618 beta=5041.483")

alpha<-1
beta<-1/2
plotGraf(function(t)
  hij(t, alpha, beta), t, title = "CF alpha=1
beta=1/2")
plotGraf(function(t)
  cfX_Beta(t, alpha, beta), t, title = "CF Charfun alpha=1
beta=1/2")
```

[image: Charfuns for different parameters]

As you can see for `alpha=beta=1` both methods deliver the same results, `cfX_Beta(t, alpha, beta)` goes wild for `alpha=121.3618` and `beta=5041.483` the result of the integration seems plausible. For `alpha=1` and `beta=1/2` the integration fails.

Comment: this is a reasonable question, but it might be hard to get answers since it will require answerers to spend a while digging into the details (I don't see an easy way to boil it down to a smaller/simpler problem, though ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work with `RcppNumerical`, at condition to use not too small tolerances (`1e-4` below).

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
#include <RcppNumerical.h>
using namespace Numer;

class BetaCDF_Re: public Func
{
private:
  double a;
  double b;
  double t;
public:
  BetaCDF_Re(double a_, double b_, double t_) : a(a_), b(b_), t(t_){}

  double operator()(const double& x) const
  {
    return R::dbeta(x, a, b, 0) * cos(t*x);
  }
};

class BetaCDF_Im: public Func
{
private:
  double a;
  double b;
  double t;
public:
  BetaCDF_Im(double a_, double b_, double t_) : a(a_), b(b_), t(t_) {}

  double operator()(const double& x) const
  {
    return R::dbeta(x, a, b, 0) * sin(t*x);
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List integrate_test(double a, double b, double t)
{
  BetaCDF_Re f1(a, b, t);
  double err_est1;
  int err_code1;
  const double res1 = integrate(f1, 0, 1, err_est1, err_code1, 
                                100, 1e-4, 1e-4,
                                Integrator<double>::GaussKronrod201);
  BetaCDF_Im f2(a, b, t);
  double err_est2;
  int err_code2;
  const double res2 = integrate(f2, 0, 1, err_est2, err_code2, 
                                100, 1e-4, 1e-4,
                                Integrator<double>::GaussKronrod201);
  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("realPart") = 
      Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("value") = res1,
        Rcpp::Named("error_estimate") = err_est1,
        Rcpp::Named("error_code") = err_code1
    ),
    Rcpp::Named("imPart") = 
      Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("value") = res2,
        Rcpp::Named("error_estimate") = err_est2,
        Rcpp::Named("error_code") = err_code2
    )
  );
}

> integrate_test(1, 0.5, 1)
$realPart
$realPart$value
[1] 0.7497983

$realPart$error_estimate
[1] 7.110548e-07

$realPart$error_code
[1] 0


$imPart
$imPart$value
[1] 0.5934922

$imPart$error_estimate
[1] 5.54721e-07

$imPart$error_code
[1] 0
```

Plot:

```
t <- seq(-100, 100, length.out = 501)
x <- lapply(t, function(t) integrate_test(1,0.5,t))
realparts <- unlist(purrr::transpose(purrr::transpose(x)$realPart)$value)
imparts <- unlist(purrr::transpose(purrr::transpose(x)$imPart)$value)
plot(t, realparts, type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(-1,1))
lines(t, imparts, type="l", col="red")
```

[image]